# Automated ML model publish in dataflow/powerbi

Tags: azure-machine-learning-service

when I am publishing the model with designer and referring in the data-flow or power-bi it is working fine. when I am trying to get the rest endpoint from the automated ML. it is showing this screen and I am not clear what to be input in this. I tried providing columns and values. it is not working. it is throwing following error.

any idea what is wrong here.

Expression.Error: We cannot convert the value "[Function]" to type Function.DetailsValue = [Function]

[image]

Comment: You can refer to similar issues: [Expression.Error: Cannot convert the value "Function" to type Function](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/bee8a8e3-c8bd-48c6-a2c3-5d00bc5031b1/expressionerror-cannot-convert-the-value-quotfunctionquot-to-type-function?forum=powerquery)

Comment: we reachout to MicroSoft and they told this is the existing bug and they will fix it soon.